# Delete preceding lines from text file if line has value

Tags: vbscript, lines

i have a text file with numbers and i must delete the lines before a given number.

```
45048 
67113.88 
74484 
597.6 
1945.65 
8714.5 
32085.9 
741.12 
1721.39 
35266.7 
8260.71 
23635.8 
40487.5 
40702.18 
29544.74 
110000 
810000 
3161000 
29201.91 
33000
```

So i must delete the lines before number 110000 . Or in another day i must delete the lines before 1721.39. I don't know how to make the deletion before the user input value. or just delete first 25 line if user prompt 25...

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\db\a.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, " ", "")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\db\a.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText

objFile.Close

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\db\a.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, "forward", "")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\db\a.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\db\a.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, ".", "")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\db\a.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\db\a.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, " ", "")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\db\a.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\db\a.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.Readline
    strLine = Trim(strLine)
    If Len(strLine) > 0 Then
        strNewContents = strNewContents & strLine & vbCrLf
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\db\a.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.Write strNewContents
objFile.Close
```

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Sorry i forgot the code :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for delete number of lines, And try yourself others.

```
Const FOR_READING = 1 
Const FOR_WRITING = 2 
strFileName = "C:\txt.txt" 
NumberOfLinesToBeDelete=inputbox("How many lines want to delete from beginning","Delete","")


Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_READING) 
strContents = objTS.ReadAll 
objTS.Close 

arrLines = Split(strContents, vbNewLine) 
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_WRITING) 

For i=0 To UBound(arrLines) 
   If i > (NumberOfLinesToBeDelete - 1) Then 
      objTS.WriteLine arrLines(i) 
   End If 
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.